# Parsing time from HTML string

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me to get hour, minutes, seconds from this code:

```
<strong class="countdown">                 23:16:27</strong>
```

I have tried with this code to get data:

```
$r = sscanf($str, "%f,%f,%f", $hour, $minutes, $secundes);
```

How to parse this countdown timer with regex or something else, and put into $hour, $minutes, $seconds? (sorry for my English)

Comment: $r = sscanf($str, "%f,%f,%f", $hour, $minutes, $secundes);

Comment: Does strtotime() not work on this?

Comment: $str = $xpath2->query("//strong[@class='countdown']"->item(0)->textContent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}/i', $str, $m)) {
    $hours = $m[1];
    $minutes = $m[2];
    $seconds = $m[3];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime(); see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/drviti):

```
<?php
$time = '23:16:27';
$time = strtotime($time);
$hour = date('g',$time);
$minute = date('i',$time);
$second = date('s',$time);
echo "hour: " . $hour . "<br>";
echo "minute: " . $minute . "<br>";
echo "second: " . $second . "<br>";
?>
```